# Is the order of array returned from C#'s Regex.Matches guaranteed to be in the order of the text?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using Regex.Matches() to parse a bunch of matches from a large text file.

Is there any documentation on this function that guarantees that the first item in the Matches array will correspond to the first match in the text, the second item in the Matches array to the second match in text, and so on?

It seems to be heavily implied based on the documentation for Regex.Match, but I can't find proof that Regex.Matches will always return the Matches in the order which they were found in the text.

**EDIT**

I found a neat website that allows you to go through the .NET source code.

So starting here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/Regex.cs,8d8851eac21ceb80

We see matches returns a new MatchCollection, which doesn't do anything because it defers execution until it's used.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexMatchCollection.cs,682620f47b442b05,references

We see that the main data structure for the MatchCollection is an ArrayList, which does guarantee order.

```
    _regex = regex;
            _input = input;
            _beginning = beginning;
            _length = length;
            _startat = startat;
            _prevlen = -1;
#if SILVERLIGHT
            _matches = new List<Match>();
#else
            _matches = new ArrayList();
#endif
            _done = false;
```

And that the GetMatch function runs the regex in the order of the text, adding each match as it goes along to the main arraylist.

```
Match match;

    do {
        match = _regex.Run(false, _prevlen, _input, _beginning, _length, _startat);

        if (!match.Success) {
            _done = true;
            return null;
        }

        _matches.Add(match);
```

That is sufficient enough of a guarantee for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the MSDN doesn't specifically state it, it's pretty clear that the matches always will be in order.  The MSDN describes how the `MatchCollection` object is lazy-loaded.  Since regex patterns are always processed in a linear fashion (either left-to-right or right-to-left), it's hard to imagine that they would be lazy-loaded in any other order.

For instance, here is an excerpt from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The MatchCollection object is populated as needed on a match-by-match basis. It is equivalent to the regular expression engine calling the Regex.Match method repeatedly and adding each match to the collection. This technique is used when the collection is accessed through its GetEnumerator method, or when it is accessed using the foreach statement (in C#) or the For Each...Next statement (in Visual Basic).

If it is the same as calling match repeatedly (passing the end position of the last match as the start position for the next one), then clearly that implies that they would be in order.

When you combine that with the presence of the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option, it becomes [even more clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#RightToLeft):

> By default, the regular expression engine searches from left to right. You can reverse the search direction by using the RegexOptions.RightToLeft option. The search automatically begins at the last character position of the string. For pattern-matching methods that include a starting position parameter, such as Regex.Match(String, Int32), the starting position is the index of the rightmost character position at which the search is to begin.

Even so, if you don't trust it, and you must guarantee the order, you could sort them by the `Match.Index` property:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).OrderBy(x=>x.Index);
```

Comment: *always processed in a left-to right linear fashion* What does `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` do then?

Comment: @PetSerAl Fair enough :)

Comment: Your solution is the smart one, I could just order it myself like that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah the difference between implementation and API.  The API does not guarantee it, yet the current implementation does (as long as you don't specify RightToLeft).  I still contend that the API is intentionally vague because it could change at some future date.  So you can assume it is always in order if you never update your version of .NET to one in which the implementation changes.

Comment: In a lazily loaded collection it is _very_ hard to imagine any other sensible implementation which would mess with the order.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee.  It will return them in the order it wants to, although it usually will return them in the order they are found.  There might be some examples where it doesn't.  If the order is absolutely critical, then sort the matches based on where they were found.

That said, I believe unless you are using some odd combination of negative look-behinds, the current implementation will always return them in the order they are in the source, but since the documentation doesn't seem to guarantee it, that may change in the future (if a more efficient multi-threaded regex engine is used, for example).  Even then, that type of change would so likely break so much stuff that it would only be enabled with some sort of flag.  So you are pretty safe assuming that, but that could change.

Comment: one upvote for understanding what the word 'guarantee' means